# UICollectionView's didSelectItemAtIndexPath only called when selecting cell with two fingers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an UICollectionView added on top of a view with a single tap gesture recogniser. The CollectionView makes use of custom cells without any subviews. The delegate's method

`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

is only called when selecting the cell with two instead of one finger or when doing a LONG press using a single finger.

I'm not accidentally overriding

`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

I read through all similar questions which were all solved by removing some kind of view or gesture recogniser.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: I'm feeling uder water rocks, can you share a simple project with it behaviour?

Comment: post your for selection please

Comment: did you tried without `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath ` ?

Comment: self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false try this

Comment: This link may helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444688/uicollectionview-only-calling-didselectitematindexpath-if-user-double-taps-will

Comment: @Janesh yes, tried with and without implementing didDeselectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Tried this, still same behaviour. This property allows you to select multiple cells at once and does not relate to the number of fingers AFAIK. Also read through similar questions trying to be a good stack overflower ;)

Comment: @Christoph test replacing 
`if(indexPath.row == self.viewModel.randomListViewModel.viewModels.count){
        [self displayRandomLocations];
    }`
With 
`NSLog`
What you seen ?

Comment: @Janesh I set my breakpoint in the first line to verify, it gets called whenever a hit the last cell with 2 fingers but not one, the condition is fine in this case. Thanks for looking into this :)

Comment: Edited my question to reflect that in fact it is also working when using a long press with a single finger. Is this some how a behaviour that can be achieved using an UICollectionView?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, resolved the issue as you can see in my answer. Still have no explanation why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution: The collection view was added on top of a view containing a single-tap gesture recogniser. This some how caused this behaviour. I removed the recogniser from the collection views parent view and it works.

*Feel free to explain why this is expected behaviour. I would have argued that the top most view (CollectionView) handles the touches before they are passed to the view behind.*

Comment: +1, this solved my problem. I'm also very curious why the collection view touch events aren't handled before they're passed on to the tap gesture recognizer though...

Comment: this was exactly the issue with me

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to removing the gesture completely is to set it so that it doesn't cancel touches in view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someSelector)];
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tapRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
tapRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Christoph solution; I've come up with this code, which is removing all the gesture recognisers in my parent view.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```